# Is it necessary to call FB.Init()?

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

We're trying to integrate the Facebook SDK just so we can track installs and the effect of Facebook ads on our mobile game on iOS.

From what I've been reading it sounds like the purpose of calling FB.Init() is to give back a page to display to the user to log them into Facebook. That's not really what we're interested in so we just ignore it. Our game doesn't need or want to log anyone into Facebook -- merely to track the install of the app by App Id. Do we even need to call this?

Is it enough merely to include the SDK and set up the settings file in our app for iOS builds?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to call it.

This method is used to initialize and setup the SDK. All other SDK methods must be called after `FB.Init()`, because they
won't exist until you do.

Comment: Just for clarity, I am not actually calling any other API's. All I am interested in is being able to see installations in Facebook's dashboard.